# Flutter Web shows emojis in black&white

Tags: flutter

In ios/android apps emojis are shown correctly. But using any web-browser (e.g. Chrome) the emoji appears in black and white. I also tried different Font-Families but with the same result.

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return const Scaffold(
          body: Center(
            child: Text('Enjoy!  If there\'s any question')
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: I have the same problem, emoji_picker_flutter also shows black and white for me on the web.

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/119536

Answer (score 23):

Due to the large size of the color emoji font (~24MB), the Flutter team made color emojis an opt-in feature in Flutter 3.10.0 ([ref](https://github.com/flutter/engine/pull/40990)).

To enable it, set the `useColorEmoji` flag to true when initializing the engine in your `index.html` file:

```
engineInitializer.initializeEngine({
  // other config...
  useColorEmoji: true,
});
```

Comment: This is a perfect solution

Comment: Doesn't work in my case

Comment: BTW I use Flutter 3.7.10

Comment: Read the answer again :)

Comment: This is clearly the correct answer @Timm Kent needs to mark this answer as correct.

Answer (score 6):

Right now, it is issue with the flutter-engine. It was probably introduced in here https://github.com/flutter/engine/commit/7406fd81865292772689a1bbbc2239c665ba07d8

The initial issue looks like the fonts provided in flutter does not have support for emoji characters (.AppleSystemUIFont) hence first fallback font is used that is NatoEmoji.

The temporary solution is to provide Apple Color Emoji font file to the web app as asset. You can find the file here
"/System/Library/Fonts/Apple Color Emoji.ttc"
You can copy this to your app's asset. Once that is done,

```yaml
...
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  universal_io: ^2.2.0
...

flutter:
  ...

  fonts:
    - family: "Apple Color Emoji"
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/apple_color_emoji.ttc
```

Then inside main.dart

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:universal_io/io.dart';

void main() async {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final fontFamilyFallback = <String>[];
    if (Platform.isIOS || Platform.isMacOS) {
      fontFamilyFallback.add("Apple Color Emoji");
    }
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(fontFamilyFallback: fontFamilyFallback),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: Center(
          child: Builder(builder: (context) {
            return const SelectableText(
              '',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 120,
              ),
            );
          }),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Please beware that the mentioned ttc file has a whopping file size of 188 MB

Comment: So the client will have to download 188 MB to use this font. It makes such a solution not suitable for production. Is there a compressed version of this font or maybe a lighter font as a replacement?

Answer (score 4):

Use Noto Color Emoji from google (follow this steps):

1. Download the font [Download Noto Color Emoji](https://fonts.google.com/noto/specimen/Noto+Color+Emoji)

2. Added it to pubspec.yaml `flutter:
   fonts:

   - family: Noto Color Emoji
     fonts:

     - asset: assets/fonts/NotoColorEmoji-Regular.ttf`
3. And in TextStyle class use it like this `TextStyle( fontFamilyFallbackm: [ 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Noto Color Emoji', ], )`

Unlike that try to:

. Delete web folder

. Update flutter by using command `flutter upgrade`

. Run command `flutter create .`

Comment: Thank you, already fixed like that. But there's no way to show iOS emojis for every device? Or at least on macos-ios browsers?

Comment: Try this https://pub.dev/packages/dart_emoji,I hope might help you

Comment: Also https://pub.dev/packages/demoji

Comment: hi, i am also facing the same problem only in web, if i try the above word spacing get increased for normal text